# Rearanging data frame table Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following kind of data frame.

```
Id   Name    Exam    Result     Exam        Result
1     Bob    Maths     10      Physics       9
2     Mar    ML        8       Chemistry     10
```

What I would like to have is removing the duplicate columns and adding their value to the corresponding rows. Something below

```
Id   Name   Exam     Result
1    Bob    Maths      10
1    Bob    Physics    9
2    Mar     ML        8
2    Mar   Chemistry   10
```

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex` by first columns, which are not duplicated by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then create `MultiIndex in columns` by counter of duplicates  nameswith [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) wotking with Series, so [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove helper level and then for `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','Name'])
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = [s, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   Id Name       Exam  Result
0   1  Bob      Maths      10
1   1  Bob    Physics       9
2   2  Mar         ML       8
3   2  Mar  Chemistry      10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative using pandas [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
#flip table into long format    
(df.melt(['Id','Name'])
 #sort by Id so that result follows immediately after Exam
 .sort_values('Id')
 #create new column on rows that have result in the variable column
 .assign(Result=lambda x: x.loc[x['variable']=="Result",'value'])
 .bfill()
 #get rid of rows that contain 'result' in variable column
 .query('variable != "Result"')
 .drop(['variable'],axis=1)
 .rename(columns={'value':'Exam'})
 )

    Id  Name    Exam       Result
0   1   Bob     Maths       10
4   1   Bob     Physics      9
1   2   Mar     ML           8
5   2   Mar    Chemistry    10
```

Alternatively, just for fun :

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','Name'])

#get boolean of duplicated columns
dupes = df.columns.duplicated()

#concatenate first columns and their duplicates
pd.concat([df.loc[:,~dupes],
           df.loc[:,dupes]
          ]).sort_index()
```